# module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'

Tags: python, pandas

No puedo abrir el archivo llamado: ejercicio.csv

mi código es:

```
df=pd.read_csv('ejercicio.csv')
```

Me da el error: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'.

No tengo ningún archivo llamado csv.py.

¿Cómo lo puedo abrir?

el archivo se llama:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿De dónde sale la variable `pd`, es decir, cómo la has creado o inicializado? Intenta un `print(pd)` y dime qué sale. Ah, otra cosa... ¿no tendrás en la misma carpeta que tu script otro que se llame `pandas.py`?

Comment: @abulafia. he usado  import pandas as pd. Para nada, lo he revisado varias veces.

Comment: De casualidad tu script se llama `csv.py`? si es el caso ponle otro nombre: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40554657/6836377

Comment: @PatricioMoracho para nada, he actualizado la pregunta para que veáis el nombre del artchivo.

Comment: Y en la carpeta dónde esta tu archivo, tienes de casualidad otro script llamado `pandas.py`? Podrias decirnos que te muestra `print(pd)`?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho para nada.. creo que la librería se ha vuelto loca. estoy haciendo otras cosas y ahora me ha error :module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Comment: @PatricioMoracho print(pd) me da <module 'pandas' (namespace)>

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `print(pd.__file__)`?

Comment: @abulafia , muestra:None

Comment: Es muy raro... debería mostrar el nombre del archivo python que ha sido cargado cuando hiciste `import pandas as pd` Por ejemplo, algo como `"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py"` (que es lo que sale al importar un pandas que funciona correctamente, aunque los nombres de carpetas pueden variar según tu instalación). Pero que muestre None es inexplicable. Habría que conocer más detalles sobre tu script completo, cómo lo ejecutas (notebook? terminal? IDE?) y qué tienes en la carpeta en que está tu script.

Comment: Estas utilizando `JupyterLab` o algo similar? Tal vez asignaste algo a `pandas` o a `pd` en algún momento y ahora por eso perdió la referencia con la libraría. Intenta reiniciar el `kernel`

Comment: @Anitta Resolver esto en comentarios va a ser imposible. Puedes entrar en esta sala de chat para mayor agilidad https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141946/ayuda

Comment: @HeytalePazguato sí, estoy utilizando jupyterlab, para nada solo he escrito 2 lineas.

Comment: @abulafia lo ejecuto con jupyter notebook, y en la cartepa donde lo tengo, solo tengo otros notebook de python y 2 ese archivo csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras una sesión de depuración en un chat, se encontró que el problema era una instalación defectuosa de anaconda. Aunque esta respuesta puede no ser útil a otros, lo que sí puede ser útil es el método de diagnóstico.

Básicamente para encontrar el problema se empezó por hacer un `print(pd)` y eso ya mostraba algo extraño ya que en lugar de decir que `pd` era un `module`, decía que era un `namespace`. Esto puede ocurrir si la carpeta en que está instalado `pandas` carece del fichero `__init__.py`, lo que ya es un síntoma preocupante.

### Encontrando la carpeta mala

El primer intento obvio, que es imprimir `pd.__file__` no funciona. Cuando `pd` no es un módulo sino un namespace, el valor de `__file__` es `None` y no nos dice por tanto desde qué archivo fue cargado pandas.

Entonces se reinició el kernel de Jupyter y se ejecutó una primera celda conteniendo:

```
import importlib
print(importlib.util.find_spec("pandas"))
```

Esto sí mostró un nombre de carpeta. Examinando la carpeta en cuestión se vio que simplemente contenía otra subcarpeta llamada `_lib`, en lugar de contener lo que cabría esperar en un paquete pandas correctamente instalado (y, como habíamos supuesto, no contenía el archivo `__init__.py`)

Por otro lado, a la OP le funcionaba correctamente el mismo notebook ejecutándolo desde VSCode. Así que se le pidió que ejecutara el código anterior en VSCode y así se vio que en este segundo caso la carpeta desde la que se cargaba pandas era otra (y ésta sí tenía la instalación correcta).

### Solución provisional

A modo de prueba, se añadió al path de python la carpeta que estaba usando VSCode y que sí funcionaba bien, con un código como este:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,r"C:\carpeta\que\averiguamos\en\vscode\que\si\funciona")
```

Con esto, el `import pandas` desde este Notebook ya funcionó correctamente.

En todo caso la solución buena será reinstalar Anaconda o pasar a usar directamente VSCode para ejecutar los notebooks.

Comment: Misteriosamente hoy funciona...